# Como se faz pra atrelar o id da questão ao id do questionário? obs: o sistema é feito em vue3 e laravel php

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

AnswerController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\Answer;
use App\Models\Question;
use App\Models\Course;
use App\Models\Questionare;
use App\Models\IntelligenceCategory;
use Inertia\Inertia;

class AnswerController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user_id = Auth::id();
        if($user_id == null){
            $user_id = 1;
        }
        $answers = $request->input('data');
        $user_answers = Answer::where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
        $answer_array = [];
        $questionare_id = $request->input('q_id');
        foreach ($answers as $id => $answer_data) {
            $answer_request = new Request($answer_data);
            $answer_request->validate([
                'q_id' => 'required|numeric|min:0',
                'value' => 'required|numeric|min:0|max:100',
            ]);
            $answer = $user_answers->where('question_id','==', $answer_request->q_id)->first(); 
            if($answer == null || Auth::id() == null){
                $answer = Answer::create([
                    'question_id' => $answer_request->q_id,
                    'value' => $answer_request->value,
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                    'comment' => $answer_request->comment
                ]);
            }else{
                $answer->value = $answer_request->value;
                $answer->comment = $answer_request->comment;
                $answer->save();
            }
            array_push($answer_array,$answer);
        }
        if(Auth::id() == null){
            $results = $this->calculate_results($answer_array);
            foreach($answer_array as $id => $answer){
                $answer->delete();
            }
            $courses = Course::all();
            return Inertia::render('Questionare/Results_Questionare', [
                'results' => $results,
                'courses' => $courses
            ]);
        }
        return redirect('/answers/'.$questionare_id);
    }

    /*
    *Function responsible for calculating the results of a quiz
    *@param $answer_array = Array of Answer models from the undertaken quiz
    */
    /*
    Suplemental function to calculate_results()
    Finds an Intelligence category in an array of intelligence categories, if not found, creates a new object
    @param Array of categories, desired category id
    @return category
    */
    public function find_or_fill_category($category_array, $category_id){
        foreach($category_array as $id => $category){
            if($category['id'] == $category_id){
                return $category;
            }
        }
        $int_cat_name = IntelligenceCategory::find($category_id)->title;
        $category =[
                'id' => $category_id,
                'name' => $int_cat_name,
                'score' => 0,
                'total' => 0,
                ];
        return $category;
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function calculate_results($answer_array)
{
    $user_id = Auth::id();
    $questionare = Questionare::findOrFail($id);
    $answer_array = [];
    foreach($questionare->questions as $id => $question){
        $answer = $question->answers->firstWhere('user_id', $user_id);
        array_push($answer_array, $answer);
    }
    // Faça os cálculos dos resultados aqui

    $courses = Course::all();
    return Inertia::render('Questionare/Results_Questionare', [
        'results' => $results, // Substitua $results pelos resultados reais calculados
        'courses' => $courses
    ]);
}


    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
    public function show($id)
    {
        // Busque a resposta com base no $id
        $answer = Answer::findOrFail($id);

        // Retorne a resposta para a visualização
        return view('answers.show', ['answer' => $answer]);
    }
}
```

QuestionareController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\Questionare;
use Inertia\Inertia;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Question;
use App\Models\IntelligenceCategory;
use App\Http\Controllers\QuestionController;

class QuestionareController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $user_id = Auth::id();
        $questionares = Questionare::all();
        return Inertia::render('Questionare/Index_Questionare',[
            'questionares' => $questionares,
            'user_id' => $user_id
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $int_categories = IntelligenceCategory::all()->toArray();
        return Inertia::render('Questionare/Create_Questionare', [
            'int_categories' => $int_categories
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user_id = Auth::id();
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'description' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'data' => 'required|array|min:1|max:255',
        ]);
        $questions = $request->input('data');
        $questionare = Questionare::create([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'user_id' => $user_id,
        ]);
        foreach ($questions as $id => $question) {            
            $qData = [
                'text' => $question['text'],
                'int_id' => $question['int_id'],
                'weight' => $question['weight'],
                'questionare_id' => $questionare->id,
                'intelligence_id' => $question['int_id'],
            ];
            $newQuestion = app('App\Http\Controllers\QuestionController')->store(new Request($qData));
        }
        return $this->index();
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $questionare = Questionare::findOrFail($id);
        $questions = $questionare->questions;
        $owner = User::findOrFail($questionare->user_id);
        if($questionare == null  || $owner == null){
            return Inertia::render('Questionare/Index_Questionare',['error' => 'error']); 
        }
        return Inertia::render('Questionare/View_Questionare', [
            'id' =>  $id,
            'questionare' => $questionare,
            'questions' => $questions,
            'owner' => $owner
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

VIew_Questionare:

```
<script setup>
import AuthenticatedLayout from '@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout.vue';
import { Head } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import { router } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js';
import 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts';
import * as plugin from './js/script.js';
import axios from 'axios';

const props = defineProps(['id', 'questionare', 'questions', 'owner']);
    </script>
    <script listing>
let currentPage = 1;
let id = 0;
let question_tracker = 1;
let quiz_tracker = 1;


    export default {
        data() {
            return {
      optionsCount: 5,
      newcomment: '',
      showCommentsSection: true,
      answers: [],
      results: [],
      isDisabled: true,
      user: {
        name: "!"
      },
      questionList: [] // Adicione o array questionList
    };
        },
        mounted(){
            plugin.my_plugin();
            //static_forms.static_form();
        },
        methods: {
            getAnswer(q_id){
                if(this.answers.find(answer => answer.q_id == q_id)){
                    return this.answers.find(answer => answer.q_id == q_id);
                }else{
                    this.answers.push({
                        id : id++,
                        q_id : q_id,
                        value : -1
                    })
                    return this.answers.find(answer => answer.q_id == q_id);
                }
            },
            shuffle(array) {
                let currentIndex = array.length,  randomIndex;

                // While there remain elements to shuffle.
                while (currentIndex != 0) {

                    // Pick a remaining element.
                    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
                    currentIndex--;

                    // And swap it with the current element.
                    [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
                    array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];
                }

                return array;
            },
            setAnswer(q_id,new_answer){
                if(this.answers.find(answer => answer.q_id == q_id)){
                    this.answers.find(answer => answer.q_id == q_id).value = new_answer;
                }else{
                    this.answers.push({
                        id : id++,
                        q_id : q_id,
                        value : new_answer,
                        comment : ''
                    })
                }
                this.isDisabled = false;
            },
            addComment(q_id, comment) {
                alert('Função chamada')
                if(this.answers.find(answer => answer.q_id == q_id)){
                    this.answers.find(answer => answer.q_id == q_id).comment = comment;
                }
            },
            postAnswers(){
                router.post('/answers/store', {
                    data: this.answers,
                    q_id: this.questionare.id
                });
            },
            getData(){
                router.get('https://unifil.test.instructure.com/api/v1/users/self');
            },
            enableDisableNextButton(){
                this.question_tracker++;
                if(this.quiz_tracker > this.question_tracker){
                    this.isDisabled = false;
                }else{
                    this.isDisabled = true;
                    this.quiz_tracker = this.question_tracker;
                }
            },
            enableNextButton(){
                this.question_tracker--;
                this.isDisabled = false;
            },
        },
        created() {
    this.shuffle(this.questions);
    this.getData();


},

    }

    </script>
    <template>
        <Head title="View Questionare" >
            <!-- Meta -->
            <!-- Meta Tags -->
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
                content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover">
            <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
            <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
            <meta name="theme-color" content="#FF8040">
            <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">

            <!-- Título -->
            <title>CUBO UniFil - UniSkills</title>

            <!-- Favicon -->
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" src="../../Components/img/apple-touch-icon.png">
            <link rel="icon" src="../../Components/img/favicon.svg">


            <!-- CSS -->
            <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

            <!-- Fontes -->
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
            <link rel="stylesheet"
                href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Figtree:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600&display=swap">
            <link rel="stylesheet"
                href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0">
        </Head>

        <AuthenticatedLayout>
            <template #header>
                <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
                    {{questionare.title}}
                </h2>
            </template>

            <div class="py-12" style="margin:5%; padding:1%; justify-content: center;">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">

                    <!-- Informações -->
                    <div class="col-lg-3 mx-0 px-0">
                        <div id="info-container" style="padding-top: 10%;padding: auto;">
                            <img class="img-fluid" style="height: 40%; margin: auto;" src='../../Components/img/apple-touch-icon.png'>
                            <h2>UniSkills {{user.name}}</h2>

                            <h3 class="my-4">Descubra o seu maior talento!</h3>
                            <p class="my-0">Este teste foi elaborado de acordo com estudos, buscando identificar o seu
                                perfil dentro de 8 habilidades intelectuais. Ao final, iremos apresentar algumas Skills.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Estrutura -->
                    <div class="col-lg-9 mx-0 px-0">

                        <!-- Barra de Progressão -->
                        <div class="progress">
                            <div aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="50"
                                class="progress-bar progress-bar-animated bg-purple" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Questionário -->
                        <div id="qbox-container">
                            <form id="form-wrapper" method="post" name="form-wrapper">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-12">


                                        <!-- Etapas / Questões -->
                                        <div id="steps-container">

                                            <!-- Questão -->
                                            <div v-for="question in questions">
                                                <div class="step" :id="'question_'+question.id">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-12">
                                                            <h5 class="text-purple">Eu afirmo que:</h5>
                                                            <h4 class="align-self-top min-vh-20">
                                                                {{question.text}}
                                                            </h4>
                                                            <div class="row align-items-center min-vh-20">
                                                                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 radio">
                                                                    <input type="radio" :name="'q_'+question.id" :id="'nao-concordo'+question.id"
                                                                        class="radio-input" :value="0" @change="setAnswer(question.id, 0)" required>
                                                                    <label :for="'nao-concordo'+question.id" class="radio-label">
                                                                        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                                                                            sentiment_dissatisfied
                                                                        </span>
                                                                        <span class="label-text">Não Concordo</span>
                                                                    </label>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 radio">
                                                                    <input type="radio" :name="'q_'+question.id"
                                                                        :id="'concordo-parcialmente'+question.id" class="radio-input"
                                                                        :value="33" @change="setAnswer(question.id, 33)">
                                                                    <label :for="'concordo-parcialmente'+question.id" class="radio-label">
                                                                        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                                                                            sentiment_neutral
                                                                        </span>
                                                                        <span class="label-text">Parcialmente</span>
                                                                    </label>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 radio">
                                                                    <input type="radio" :name="'q_'+question.id" :id="'concordo'+question.id"
                                                                        class="radio-input" :value="67" @change="setAnswer(question.id, 67)">
                                                                    <label :for="'concordo'+question.id" class="radio-label">
                                                                        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                                                                            sentiment_satisfied
                                                                        </span>
                                                                        <span class="label-text">Concordo</span>
                                                                    </label>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 radio">
                                                                    <input type="radio" :name="'q_'+question.id"
                                                                        :id="'concordo-plenamente'+question.id" class="radio-input"
                                                                        :value="100" @change="setAnswer(question.id, 100)">
                                                                    <label :for="'concordo-plenamente'+question.id" class="radio-label">
                                                                        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                                                                            sentiment_very_satisfied
                                                                        </span>
                                                                        <span class="label-text">Plenamente</span>
                                                                    </label>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <!-- Seção de comentários -->
                                                                <h3>Comentários</h3>

                                                                <!-- Lista de comentários -->
                                                                <div class="comments-section">
                                                                <ul>
                                                                    <li>
                                                                        <h1 v-if="this.answers.find(answer => answer.q_id == question.id)">
                                                                            {{ this.answers.find(answer => answer.q_id == question.id) }}
                                                                        </h1>
                                                                        <h1 v-else>Oh no </h1>

                                                                    </li>
                                                                </ul>


                                                                <!-- Formulário para adicionar um novo comentário -->
                                                                    <p>Message is: {{ newcomment }}</p>
                                                                    <input v-model="newcomment" type="text"/>
                                                                    <button v-on:click="addComment(question.id, newcomment)">Comentar</button>
                                                                </div>


                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>



                                            <!-- Compilação -->
                                            <div class="step">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-12">
                                                        <h2 class="text-purple">Estamos quase lá...</h2>
                                                        <p>Os resultados são considerados como uma de suas fontes de
                                                            informação.
                                                            Clique em
                                                            <strong class="text-purple">"Continuar"</strong>.
                                                        </p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-12 text-center">
                                                        <img class="img-fluid my-2" src="../../Components/img//analista-dados.svg">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-12">

                                        <!-- Controle -->
                                        <div id="q-box__buttons" class="mt-2">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mr-2" id="prev-btn" @click="enableNextButton()">Voltar</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mr-2" id="next-btn" @click="enableDisableNextButton()" :disabled="isDisabled">Próximo</button>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="submit-btn" @click="postAnswers()">Continuar</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <!-- Carregador -->
        <div id="preloader-wrapper">
            <div id="preloader"></div>
            <div class="preloader-section section-left"></div>
            <div class="preloader-section section-right"></div>
        </div>
        <component is="script" href="js/script.js" async></component>
        <!--component is="script" href="js/static-forms.js" async></component -->
        </AuthenticatedLayout>
    </template>
```

Comment: Considerando que [esta pergunta já foi feita](/q/587692/70) e as orientações já foram dadas lá, o espaço de comentários foi desativado nesta segunda versão. Queira editar a original conforme orientado (observando todos os requisitos já passados) para que ela seja reavalida pela comunidade.